# C# - how does variable scope and disposal impact processing efficiency?

Tags: c#, performance, scope, cpu-usage, dispose

I was having a discussion with a colleague the other day about this hypothetical situation. Consider this pseudocode:

```
public void Main()
{   
    MyDto dto = Repository.GetDto();

    foreach(var row in dto.Rows)
    {
        ProcessStrings(row);
    }
}

public void ProcessStrings(DataRow row)
{
    string string1 = GetStringFromDataRow(row, 1);
    string string2 = GetStringFromDataRow(row, 2);

    // do something with the strings
}
```

Then this functionally identical alternative:

```
public void Main()
{
    string1 = null;
    string2 = null,
    MyDto dto = Repository.GetDto();

    foreach(var row in dto.Rows)
    {
        ProcessStrings(row, string1, string2)
    }
}

public void ProcessStrings(DataRow row, string string1, string string2)
{
    string1 = GetStringFromDataRow(row, 1);
    string2 = GetStringFromDataRow(row, 2);

    // do something with the strings
}
```

How will these differ in processing when running the compiled code? Are we right in thinking the second version is marginally more efficient because the string variables will take up less memory and only be disposed once, whereas in the first version, they're disposed of on each pass of the loop?

Would it make any difference if the strings in the second version were passed by `ref` or as `out` parameters?

Comment: They are not being disposed. They are being GC'd.

Comment: I'd expect the second version to be slightly *slower* because you're passing in arguments that aren't necessary. You're trading local variables for arguments, but both are just references to the actual string objects.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet On the cpu-level both of these examples may handle their variables and parameters using cpu registers and/or stack, which may or may not actually have identical execution profiles. In other words, even though the C# code is different, there may not actually be a difference at all in the final code. It is likely that some code is moved, however, but I doubt this will matter other than on a highly theoretical level.

Comment: There is no difference performancewise at-least. You are wasting your time in a futile debate. Better spend your time on some other topic :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're dealing with "marginally more efficient" level of optimizations you risk not seeing the whole picture and end up being "marginally less efficient".

This answer here risks the same thing, but with that caveat, let's look at the hypothesis:

> Storing a string into a variable *creates a new instance* of the string

No, not at all. A string is an object, what you're storing in the variable is a reference to that object. On 32-bit systems this reference is 4 bytes in size, on 64-bit it is 8. Nothing more, nothing less. Moving 4/8 bytes around is overhead that you're not really going to notice a lot.

So neither of the two examples, with the very little information we have about the makings of the methods being called, creates more or less strings than the other so on this count they're equivalent.

So what is different?

Well in one example you're storing the two string references into local variables. This is most likely going to be cpu registers. Could be memory on the stack. Hard to say, depends on the rest of the code. Does it matter? Highly unlikely.

In the other example you're passing in two parameters as `null` and then reusing those parameters locally. These parameters can be passed as cpu registers or stack memory. Same as the other. Did it matter? Not at all.

So most likely there is going to be absolutely no difference at all.

Note one thing, you're mentioning "disposal". This term is reserved for the usage of objects implementing `IDisposable` and then the act of disposing of these by calling `IDisposable.Dispose` on those objects. Strings are not such objects, this is not relevant to this question.

If, instead, by disposal you mean "garbage collection", then since I already established that neither of the two examples creates more or less objects than the others due to the differences you asked about, this is also irrelevant.

This is not important, however. It isn't important what you or I or your colleague *thinks* is going to have an effect. Knowing is quite different, which leads me to...

The real tip I can give about optimization:

1. Measure
2. Measure
3. Measure
4. Understand
5. Verify that you understand it correctly
6. Change, if possible

You measure, use a profiler to find the real bottlenecks and real time spenders in your code, then understand why those are bottlenecks, then ensure your understanding is correct, then you can see if you can change it.

In your code I will venture a guess that if you were to profile your program you would find that those two examples will have absolutely no effect whatsoever on the running time. If they *do* have effect it is going to be on order of nanoseconds. Most likely, the very act of looking at the profiler results will give you one or more "huh, that's odd" realizations about your program, and you'll find bottlenecks that are far bigger fish than the variables in play here.

Comment: Thanks. We do measure stuff, and were aware that the impact of this difference would likely be negligible. It's just a matter of curiosity and wanting to learn about how compiled code is eventually interpreted by the processor.

Comment: On this level of detail I would write the code that gives you the most warm fuzzies and leave the compiler to the actual details. In other words, go for example #1.

Answer (score 2):

In both of your alternatives, `GetStringFromDataRow` creates new string every time. Whether you store a *reference* to this string in a local variable or in argument parameter variable (which is essentially not much different from local variable in your case) does not matter. Imagine you even not assigned result of `GetStringFromDataRow` to any variable - instance of string is still created and stored somewhere in memory until garbage collected. If you would pass your strings by reference - it won't make much difference. You will be able to reuse memory location to store *reference* to created string (you can think of it as the memory address of string instance), but not memory location for string contents.